# CAML : Cannot complete this action

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

It seems my following query is failing and throwing "Cannot complete this action".However when I test this query in CAML Query builder it's working fine.

```
<Where>
    <And>
       <Or>
         <Eq><FieldRef Name='Participant' /><Value Type='User'>Test1</Value></Eq>
         <Eq><FieldRef Name='Participant' /><Value Type='User'>Test2</Value></Eq>
         <Eq><FieldRef Name='Participant' /><Value Type='User'>Test3</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Value Type='Text'>Positioning</Value></Eq>
     </And>
 </Where>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And and Or elements have exactly 2 children. Your Or statement needs to be rephrased as

```
<Or>
  <Eq><FieldRef Name='Participant' /><Value Type='User'>Test1</Value></Eq>
  <Or>
     <Eq><FieldRef Name='Participant' /><Value Type='User'>Test2</Value></Eq>
     <Eq><FieldRef Name='Participant' /><Value Type='User'>Test3</Value></Eq>
  </Or>
</Or>
```

Comment: @Igaud, Thanks.. I'm generating query dynamically and my <OR> condition can increase up to any limit.What's the best way to arrange ?